# Runtime error. I know where but I don't know why and how to correct it

Tags: c++, eclipse, pointers, struct, linked-list

After the first problem have been solved, I got another problem. It happens on the while loop

```
while (!infile.eof())
```

The result is the same when it is

```
while (getline(infile, line))
```

seems that somehow it fail to check the condition or something, and then it just crash again.

[The following part have been SOLVED]

This is the function. After inserting tonnes of cout to see what's happening, this

```
curr->prev = a->start;
```

is the line causes the run time error. The whole function is here:

```
busRoute readlist(const char* filename)
{
    busRoute *a;
    a = new busRoute;       //a new bus route
    stop_pointer curr;
    stop_pointer pre;
    fstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);
    string route="";
    string line="";
    int i=0;
    float df, ef;
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        getline(infile, route);            //read route number in string
        a->routeNo=atoi(route.c_str());     //convert and store route num in int
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            i++;
            getline(infile, line);//read text
            //generate linked list
            unsigned int pos;
            string b,c,d,e;
            pos = line.find(",");
            if (pos <100000)
            {
                b = line.substr(0,pos); //stop name
                c = line.substr(pos+1, line.length()-pos+2);
                pos = c.find(",");
                d = c.substr(0, pos);     //latitude in string
                e = c.substr(pos+1, c.length()-pos+2);    //longitude in string
                df = atof (d.c_str());    //latitude in float
                ef = atof (e.c_str());    //longitude in float
                //store b c d e into a
                if (i<2)
                {
                    a->start->stop_name= b;
                    a->start->latitude=df;
                    a->start->longitude=ef;
                    a->start->prev=NULL;
                    curr = a->start->next;

                    //sth wrong with curr->prev

                    curr->prev = a->start;
                }
                else
                {
                    curr->stop_name=b;
                    curr->latitude=df;
                    curr->longitude=ef;
                    curr->next = new stop_node;
                    pre = curr;
                    curr = curr->next;
                    curr->prev = pre;
                }
            }
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    return *a;
}
```

and the following is the .h

```
typedef struct stop_node* stop_pointer;

typedef struct stop_node {
  string stop_name;  // the name of the stop
  float latitude; // the latitude of the geographic coordinates of the stop
  float longitude; // the longitude of the geographic coordinates of the stop
  stop_pointer next; // the next pointer
  stop_pointer prev; // the prev pointer
};

typedef struct busRoute {
  int routeNo;  // the route number of the stop
  stop_pointer start;  // the head of the linked list
};
```

Can someone explain to me what mistake I am making? Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the runtime error is? Does the program crash, or does it behave in an unexpected way?

Comment: Using `eof()` is almost always a bug. Say `while(getline(infile, line))` instead.

Comment: @Frank It crashed. The normal "abc.exe has stop working. Windows can check online blah blah blah"

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, but this does not solve the current problem.

Comment: @Louis: Well, there's not much C++ in this code, it feels like more C for the most part. Is this some kind of exercise or real code? In real code, you would use the standard std::list class if you wanted a linked list, rather than attempting to implement it yourself.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes it is some sort of exercise, where using struct is a must. also, I have used using namespace std to replace all std::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the first time `a->start->next;` is pointing to some garbage value ...

So when you try

```
curr = a->start->next;
```

So here you are assigning garbage value to curr

```
curr->prev = a->start;
```

And here you are trying to access the invalid location resulting runtime error..Hope this will help...

///Changes made for the code to work...

```
                if (i<2)
                {
                    a->start->stop_name= b;
                    a->start->latitude=df;
                    a->start->longitude=ef;
                    a->start->prev=NULL;
                   //adding 
                    a->start->next=NULL;
                    curr = a->start;

            }
            else
            {
                curr->next=new stop_node;
                curr->next->prev=curr;
                curr->stop_name=b;
                curr->latitude=df;
                curr=curr->next;
                curr->next= NULL;
            }
```

There is problem with you struct declaration...

remove this

```
//typedef struct stop_node* stop_pointer;

typedef struct stop_node {
  string stop_name;  // the name of the stop
  float latitude; // the latitude of the geographic coordinates of the stop
  float longitude; // the longitude of the geographic coordinates of the stop
  stop_node *next; // the next pointer
  stop_node *prev; // the prev pointer
};


typedef struct busRoute {
  int routeNo;  // the route number of the stop
  //stop_pointer start;  // the head of the linked list
  stop_node start;       
};
```

if `start` is a pointer-type; you need to dynamically allocate the memory and then access the memory. So it will go like this

a->start = new bus_node();

To avoid the complication use the above definition of struct and Use . operator to access members of start in rest of the code. For eg. `a->start.next = NULL`

Comment: How can I change a->start->next into something not a garbage value?

Comment: Now it stuck in somewhere else. It runs the if(i<2) perfectly, and seems that something is wrong with the loop. After inserting a bunch of cout again, I found that it crash right after finishing the first loop. But then it fail to enter the loop again.

Comment: have added the finding ... see it should work now...also instead of using cout for debugging use gdb if you are using linux or visual studio writing programs in windows...